# how to make the span element go to the next line using css

Tags: html, css

I am using a tool which pre generates the code , but we can manipulate some of the code using php,javascript,html and css. 
so i have a hyperlink which has the image and label for it. but i need the label to be displayed below the image.
this is way the generated code is there

```
<a href="#">
    <image src='...'>
    <span>label</span>
</a>
```

So I need to give a line break before the span element. how can i do that?

I tried to use the following css, but it didn't work:

```
span {
    display: inline;
}

span:before {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `display:block` would work.

Comment: thank you for your immediate response. but, it didn't work

Comment: The right way to do this is really styling instead of hacking the markup.

Answer (score 0):

try this . it may solve your problem

```
<style>
span {
display: block;
margin-top:5px;
border-top:1px solid #dedede;
padding-top:5px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `<br>` tag in html creates a space 
 which looks like this^ 
 The `<hr>` (horizontal ruler) will  create a space as well as line,

---

which looks like this^

```
 <a href="application">
 <image details>
 <br>
 <span>label </span></a>
```

The `<br>` tag doesn't have to appear in a newline in the actual html, `<image details><br>` is also perfectly valid, my personal preference is to write it like on it's own line for clarity

Comment: Thank you Richard. yes i have used both <br> and <hr> before but the problem here is i cannot change the pre generated code. i need to add the code after the tool finishes generating the source code.

Comment: @ktann ah I see, weird. You can try adding 'width:100%' to the span css and so it will take up the entire width of it's container, that should force it down beneath the image. you may have to add 'position:relative' as well